# What does it mean when a file has a ?? file name?

Tags: command-line, ssh

I tried to generate a new SSH key pair

```
jacob@mystuff:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "GitLab" -b 4096

jacob@mystuff:~$ ls -la
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 jacob jacob 4096 Feb 18 00:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Feb 18 00:05 ..
-rw------- 1 jacob jacob 3326 Feb 18 00:09 ??
-rw-r--r-- 1 jacob jacob  220 Feb 18 00:05 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 jacob jacob 3771 Feb 18 00:05 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 jacob jacob  655 Feb 18 00:05 .profile
-rw-r--r-- 1 jacob jacob  732 Feb 18 00:09 ??.pub
drwxrwxr-x 2 jacob jacob 4096 Feb 18 00:08 .ssh

jacob@mystuff:~$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
cat: /home/jacob/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Were you prompted to enter a keyfile ("`Enter file in which to save the key`")? it looks like you were - and you answered `??`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` only prints out question marks without there actually being questions marks at that spot in a file's name if the switch `-q` or the equivalent long switch `--hide-control-chars` is set. Which it isn't. This means you have a file which literally is called `??`.

steeldriver's hypothesis is probably correct: You stated `??` as the name of the key when `ssh-keygen` ran.

This is quite evident because `ssh-keygen` was run right before `ls` and when executed successfully, it creates a file containing the private key (possibly encrypted) (whose name you may choose) and a file containing the public key which starts with the name of the file containing the private key but has `.pub` in the end. There is a file called `??` and one called `??.pub`, so this makes perfect sense.

As with all other things with a default value you were asked to state, you could've just pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the default value for the key files' locations.

To change the file name and location to the one of the default key, execute these commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
mv ~/?? ~/.ssh/id_rsa
mv ~/??.pub ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

The first one creates the folder `.ssh` in your home directory if it doesn't already exist, the second one moves your private key into it, and the third one moves your public key into it.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the *right* way to accept the default file location suggested by `ssh-keygen` is simply to hit `Enter`

Comment: @steeldriver You're right. That's probably worth noting. I added it and furthermore added that that's always possible when there is a default value.

Comment: @UTF-8 I know I did not enter `??`. I've used this command a million times. I've been set up ssh keys for years. I pressed the Enter key for sure to accept the defaults.

Comment: That's the only explanation I can think of. I just checked the source code of `ssh-keygen` to see whether it uses question marks in some cases. The only question marks I came across were in input evaluation, output messages  (not just a question and nothing else like what I was looking for), and symbols of tertiary operators. Unless there is a very weird bug which entered 2 question marks when you hit the enter key, there isn't any explanation I can think of.